# I am doing text detection from an image

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

```
img = cv2.imread('D:\textdect3_files\text1.jpg', 0);
vis = img.copy()
mser = cv2.MSER()
```

after running the code I am getting this type of error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'.
how can i solve this type of error?

Comment: you have to use double slashes `\\ `  instead of one. If not it will take the character `\t` that is a tab....

Comment: Please read this ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The returned image is None. From the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

> Warning Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but
>   print img will give you None

This is most likely because you have the wrong image path ('D:\textdect3_files\text1.jpg')

Make sure your image exists at the path and you have permissions to read from that location via your python code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the image path is incorrect so that the `'NoneType'` error was thrown. To fix it, modify the path as below.

1. `img = cv2.imread('D:\\textdect3_files\\text1.jpg', 0)` or
2. `img = cv2.imread('D:/textdect3_files/text1.jpg', 0)` or
3. `img = cv2.imread(r'D:\textdect3_files\text1.jpg', 0)`